# Send checkbox value from child popup to parent

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I'm trying to send the value of a checkbox back on a child popup back to its parent. I can do this with text boxes but not with the check box. This is what I have

```
var chkSiteVisitRequired = opener.document.getElementById('chkSiteVisit')

if (document.getElementById('<%= chkSiteVisit.ClientID %>').checked)
            chkSiteVisitRequired.checked = true;
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the value of `chkSiteVisit.ClientID`? Some ID's are invalid in HTML and can't actually be used successfully.

Comment: I've just realised that I had an on checked event in my checkbox definition. Fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the example below.You can just copy and paste it inside a new .aspx page and it will work.Step through the javascript code and understand how it works then apply to your problem:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#checkState").click(function () {
                var chkSiteVisitRequired = document.getElementById('<%= chkSiteVisit.ClientID %>');

                if (chkSiteVisitRequired.checked)
                    alert('checked');
                else
                    alert('not checked');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSiteVisit" runat="server" />
        <input id="checkState" type="button" value="Check State" />
    </form>
</body>
```